# How to Connect to Docker Postgres Container from Host Machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, rails-postgresql, remote-connection

I put together a Rails dev environment by following instructions from
https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

It works, but I am unable to connect to the Postgres server from the host machine. I am running macOS High Sierra. When I run `docker container ls` I see `5432/tcp` as the port for the Postgres container. Note that there's not IP listed in front of 5432. When I run `docker network inspect <postgress_container_ID>` I get 172.18.0.2 as the IP.

But when I run `psql -h 172.18.0.2 -p 5432  -U postgres` I get

```
xpsql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
  Is the server running on host "172.18.0.2" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By looking at your details **5432/tcp**, It seems to me you have not exported port number **5432**.

if you have exported port, then it should look like.

```
 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```

and then by using HOST IP address (your local mac machine ip) you should be able to connect, if still not work, please share your docker command - how you are running container?

Docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/airbnb
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

In your docker-compose file, you are not exposing port number 5432, hence from externally you won't able to connect Postgres DB.

Try adding  **ports: - "5432:5432"** in your docker-compose file.
and then by using your machine IP address, you should able to connect database.

Comment: can you please share docker run command, how you are running Postgres container?

Comment: I followed the instructions from https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ to the letter. So, I start the container by running `docker-compose up`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: My doubt was correct - you are not exposing port 5432 :) Please look at my updated answer above, add that port number in your docker-compose file. While adding please be aware of correctly formatting docker-compose file (extra spaces).

Answer (score 2):

By default, [postgres exposes port 5432](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/1805adb0693d9602bfb19b6bf2583b311c43b749/10/Dockerfile#L132). This will only expose the port to other containers within the same Docker network -- i.e. all the other containers in the compose file. This is because by default, [docker compose creates a network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for all the containers in the compose file.

You have a few options for connecting to a container from the host:

1. [Expose the port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) with `HOST:CONTAINER` format which will make the container's port available on `HOST` IP. For example, use `127.0.0.1:5432` so you can access the port at that address on your host.
2. Use the Docker network's gateway IP as the interface/source address. For example, if the container is `172.18.0.2`, then likely the gateway is `172.18.0.1`. There's usually a way to do this with postgres and socket libraries, but unfortunately I don't see a way to do it with `psql`.
3. Set up IP tables so your host can access the Docker network.

Another option is to access it from a container within the Docker network. You can do `docker-compose run --rm db psql -h db -U postgres` which will run a one-off container with the same Docker image as the `db` container and within the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP of the VM where Docker is actually running. You can find this IP by running:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

Comment: I don't think it's running on docker-machine. Running docker-machine ls returns an empty resultset